# Difference between biunique and unique

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In dictionaries in internet it saids

> biunique: being a correspondence between two sets that is one-to-one in both directions.

Then with Equivalence Theorem of F. Bernstein

> If each of two given sets is
> equivalent to a subset of the other, then the two given sets are themselves equivalent.

> (Or equivalently, If two sets having injective map in both direction then they are equivalent.)

it seems biunique has same meaning with equivalent.
Am I correct?

Comment: See [Equivalent sets](https://www.britannica.com/science/set-theory/Equivalent-sets) and [Bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection)

Comment: [biunique](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/biunique): adjective, being a correspondence between two sets that is one-to-one in both directions.

Comment: "Biunique" is (a seldomly used term for) a quality of a mapping, "equivalent" is thing sets (is this case) may be.

Comment: Thanks. now I've got the point, biquique is a property of mapping but equivalent is relation between sets. Thus, my question should be is biunique has same meaning with bijection? and it's answer should be yes. / I misunderstood biunique as a property of two sets that can have injection in each direction.

Comment: When searching for "biunique", I have to search through pages to find any mention other than dictionary definitions. (Or else instances of "Bi-Unique" as a brand for some product.) It is possible this was a rarely used alternative name for a bijection that has since fallen almost completely out of favor,